# JSON Schema - complex validation within array

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have an array. This can contain several testObjects.

```
"testObject": {
  "$id": "#/properties/items/testObject",
  "type": "array",
  "minItems": 1,
  "items": {
    "$id": "#/properties/testObject/items",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "id",
      "testObjectType",
      "title"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "$id": "#/items/id",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "testObjectType": {
        "$id": "#/items/testObjectType",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "title": {
        "$id": "#/items/title",
        "type": "string"
      }
     }
   }
```

Let's say I wanna ensure, that depending on the testObjectType, another title is allowed.

```
"allOf": [
 {
   {
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "testObject": {
        "properties": {
          "testObjectType": {
            "const": "typ1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "testObject": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "const": "testTitle 1"
          }
        }
      }
 }
]
```

E.g. if I would do it that way, I can only validate a specific item. But if testObject is an array in another object, I need to have this validation for each items.

To make it more concrete. This is the input:

```
    {
  "root-element": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "testObjectType": "testObject 1",
      "title": "title 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "testObjectType": "testObject 2",
      "title": "title 2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "testObjectType": "testObject 3",
      "title": "title 3",
      "anotherAttribute": "anotherValue"
    }
  ]
}
```

In case testObjectType is "testObject 3", I want to ensure anotherAttribute is also there.

Second validation for "testObject 2", title must be "title 2". 
I see the problem, that all those objects are within an array and do not know how to validate each element

Comment: Do you know all the possible values up front? If you do, it's possible. Otherwise it is not possible.

Comment: seems I found the solution. It is possible. I can use if directly in the schema and do not have to use it in the "allOf" section outside of it.

Comment: OK, but you still need to wrap in an `allOf` if you want to use multiple `if` conditions. Remember, objects with duplicate keys is undefined behaviour in JSON.

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is asking. If you don't plan to expand it now you've found your solution, then consider deleting your question.